# Does the ExtensionDataObject need to be public?

Tags: .net, wcf

When used in WCF (SOAP), does the ExtensionDataObject need to be marked as public for it to work as intended?

I would assume that it would need to be public but if it would still work while marked as internal, it would be nice to not have to property show up to the developer using the Web Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if you add the ExtensionDataObject property in the outer-most ServiceBehavior class (the .svc file) it will automatically add the ExtensionDataObject to all of the classes that it uses in the web service so there's no need to do it for every class that's used in your service.